# Changing the structure of np.array in Python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have the following array structure.

`array([[ 0.3,  0.1,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  2.7],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  0. ,  6. ],
       [ 0.6,  0.4, -1. ,  0. ,  0. ,  1. ,  6. ]])`

How can I change to the following structure?

`array([[ 0.3,  0.1,  0. ,  1. , 2.7],
       [ 0.5,  0.5,  0. ,  0. , 6. ],
       [ 0.6,  0.4, -1. ,  0. , 6. ]])`

Answer (score 2):

Assuming array is stored in a variable `arr` use indexing:

```
arr[:,[0, 1, 2, 3, 6]]
```